# Angular connect to ASP.NET API SignalR Hub return 404 Not Found (Identity Server 3)

Tags: .net, angular, asp.net-web-api, signalr

I have SignalR communication between Angular 8 and ASP.NET Web API, .NET Framework 4.7.2 which was working correctly perfectly. However I havent tested this in a months and now when I tried i have that result in the browser console:

http://localhost:55454/signalr/negotiate? .... net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

The only major change in these few months is that now my API uses Identity Server 3, but i do not think this is the problem.

Howeever here is my code in StartUp before Identity Server implementation:

```
            app.Map("/signalr", map =>
        {
            map.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
            var hubConfiguration = new HubConfiguration
            {
                EnableJSONP = true,
                EnableDetailedErrors = true,

            };

            map.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions()
            {
                Provider = new QueryStringOAuthBearerProvider(),
                AccessTokenProvider = new AuthenticationTokenProvider()
                {
                    OnCreate = new Action<AuthenticationTokenCreateContext>(c =>
                    {
                        c.SetToken(c.SerializeTicket());
                    }),
                    OnReceive = new Action<AuthenticationTokenReceiveContext>(c =>
                    {
                        c.DeserializeTicket(c.Token);
                        c.OwinContext.Environment["Properties"] = c.Ticket.Properties;
                    })
                },
            });

            map.RunSignalR(hubConfiguration);
        });
```

And the QueryStringOAuthBearerProvider (since i sent the token in the Query String):

```
        private class QueryStringOAuthBearerProvider : OAuthBearerAuthenticationProvider
    {
        public override Task RequestToken(OAuthRequestTokenContext context)
        {
            if (context != null)
            {
                var value = context.Request.Query.Get("token");

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
                {
                    context.Token = value;
                }
            }

            return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
        }
    }
```

I tried with the new piece of code but result is still the same:

```
            app.UseIdentityServerBearerTokenAuthentication(new 
              IdentityServerBearerTokenAuthenticationOptions
              {
                Authority = identityAuthority,
              });


       app.Map("/signalr", map =>
        {
            map.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
            var hubConfiguration = new HubConfiguration
            {
                EnableJSONP = true,
                EnableDetailedErrors = true,

            };

            map.UseIdentityServerBearerTokenAuthentication(new IdentityServer3.AccessTokenValidation.IdentityServerBearerTokenAuthenticationOptions
            {
                Authority = identityAuthority,
                TokenProvider = new QueryStringOAuthBearerProvider(),
            });
            map.RunSignalR(hubConfiguration);
        });
    }
```

I think this is not the major problem since in Debug it never hits the breakpoint in the QueryStringOAuthBearerProvider class. And it got to be.

My SignalR version in the API is 2.4.1, so it is in the Angular ("signalr": "^2.4.1",)
I also use "ng2-signalr": "^8.0.2" nuget to save some JS code manually written.

Here is an example in the Typescript (which was prevoiusly working):

```
    startConnection(hubConnection: SignalR): Promise<ISignalRConnection> {
    console.log('Connecting...');

    if (this.authService && this.authService.token) {
        return hubConnection.connect({ jsonp: true, hubName: 'ChatHub', url: this.config.API_BASE_URL, qs: { token: this.authService.token } });
    }
}
```

Maybe is the StartUp configuration, but maybe not cause it looks like it doesnt find such address at all (localhost/signalr...)
CORS policy for this angular project is set, all other regular API calls are working without problem.

I can`t figure out why i hot this 404 error from some functionality that was working as a charm not so long ago.

EDIT:

In the database I keep the localhost address of the Angular App and I gave him full CORS access, but is this enough for the SignalR? Yes request comes from the same localhost, but  does not call http://localhost:55454/api but http://localhost:55454/signalr, so should something additional be done with the CORS? I think it may should, otherwise why this line of the OLD Code was added:

```
       app.Map("/signalr", map =>
    {
        map.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
```

Any toughts?

Comment: I belive that you should configure CORS before map the hub.

Comment: this CORS config is from old implementation because with the Identity Server 3 I kept the CORS Origins in their own table in the DB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved that. The initial reponse was NOT very detailed. 404 and that`s it. But when i got deeper, i found that the detailed response is:

HTTP Error 404.15 - Not Found The request filtering module is configured to deny a request where the query string is too long.

And indeed it is. So now I need to decide is it safe to increase URL and query string length and if not... how to solve this.